# Send a mail to a group which contains contacts

Tags: drupal, civimail

After creating a group. I have added contacts to this group and when I try to send a mail to a group I am  blocked  by an error and the mail does not go. I remind you that

- sending email for each contact individually works
- 'on hold' flag off
  Cheers

Comment: Could you describe the error and the steps you do to send out the mailing?

Comment: step of my configuration and errors:
-creation of an intelligent or simple group
-creation of contacts
-go to Administer>civimail>civimail components setting
checked on 'Enable multiple bulk email address for a contact'.
-go to mailings>new Maillings
-I enter the information
-I select the group
-then sending

Comment: errors:
- could not identify any recipients. Perhaps the group is empty
-email on hold-generally due to bouncing

Comment: Did you add the contacts to the group and do they all have valid email-addresses?

Comment: yeah. all this correct

Comment: OK weird. If the contacts do not have the optout flag, the email address is not inactive and the contacts are in the mailing group (with the status added) there is probably a bug or problem with your setup. You may want to add details such as you CMS and CiviCRM version to the question so may help you with debugging.

Comment: okay i using drupal 8.9.2  with civicrm 5.27.2